# Planarity of $k-$trees

Tags: graph-theory

I am studying $k-$trees and partial $k-$trees and I want to prove the following three facts:

1. A $k-$tree is planar if $k<3$
2. A $k-$tree is not planar if $k>3$
3. A $3-$tree is planar if and only if it does not contain the graph $Q$ as a contraction (meaning that $Q$ can not be obtained from $G$ by contracting edges of $G$), where $Q$ is the graph we obtain from $K_6$ (the complete graph on $6$ vertices) if we remove the edges of one of its triangles

The definition of a $k-$tree, as I have it in my notes, is the following:

> A graph is a $k-$tree if
>
> $\bullet$ The graph is $K_{k+1}$
>
> $\bullet$ The graph can be obtained from a $k-$tree $H$ if we add a new vertex to $H$ and connect it with all the vertices of some $k-$clique of $H$

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have a recursive definition. So for (1), a proof by induction is a natural approach. Claim (2) should be easy to prove. If $k > 3$, does a $k$-tree contain $K_{5}$?